# Play2 MongoDb new insert updates record

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, insert

I am trying to do a CRUD form for a simple product page. I am having a weird issue where in whenever I try to insert a new product I always the old product getting updated and hence there is always one product which gets updated every time I do a save.

My `index.scala.html` is as follows

```
@main("Product List"){

@inputText(productForm("search"),'_label -> "Search",'id -> "search")

<h3>@products.size() product(s)</h3>

<table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Promo Price</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>On Sale</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @for(product <- products){
        <tr>
        <td>
            @product.title
        </td>
        <td>
            @product.pricing.cost
        </td>
        <td>
            @product.pricing.price
        </td>
        <td>
            @product.pricing.promoPrice
        </td>
        <td>
            @product.pricing.savings
        </td>
        <td>
            @product.pricing.onSale
        </td>
        <td>    
            @helper.form(action = routes.Application.deleteProduct(product.id)){
                <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
            }
        </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Add new product</h2>
@form(action = routes.Application.newProduct()){
    @inputText(productForm("title"),'_label -> "Title")
    @inputText(productForm("pricing.cost"),'_label -> "Cost")
    @inputText(productForm("pricing.price"),'_label -> "Price")
    @inputText(productForm("pricing.promoPrice"),'_label -> "Promo Price")
    @inputText(productForm("pricing.savings"),'_label -> "Savings")
    @checkbox(productForm("pricing.onSale"),'_label -> "On Sale")
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add"/>
}
}
```

My `Application.java` is as follows,

```
public class Application extends Controller {
....
static Form<Product> productForm = new Form<Product>(Product.class);

public static Result products() {
        return ok(views.html.index.render(Product.all(), productForm));
    }

public static Result newProduct() {
        Form<Product> filledForm = productForm.bindFromRequest();
        if (productForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(views.html.index
                    .render(Product.all(), filledForm));
        } else {
            Product.create(filledForm.get());
            return redirect(routes.Application.products());
        }
    }
}
```

And my model `Product.java` is as follows,

```
public class Product {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 94587092799205246L;

    @Id
    public long id;

    @Required
    public String title;

    @Required
    public Pricing pricing;

    public Product(){
    }

    public Product(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    private static JacksonDBCollection<Product, Long> products = MongoDB
            .getCollection("product", Product.class, Long.class);

    public static List<Product> all() {
        return Product.products.find().toArray();
    }

    public static void create(Product product) {
        Product.products.save(product);
    }

    public static void delete(Long id) {
        Product p = Product.products.findOneById(id);
        if(p != null){
            Product.products.remove(p);
        }
    }

}
```

I am not sure if it is because the form is declared as static or the form doesn't get cleared somewhere. An extra pair of eyes would be of a great help here. Thanks for your time

Comment: whats the id of this object that is being update in your db ?

Comment: > db.product.find()
{ "_id" : NumberLong(0), "title" : "Potato", "pricing" : { "cost" : 10, "price" : 20, "promoPrice" : 10, "savings" : 10, "onSale" : true } }

Comment: @marcinn It kind of keeps updating this object again and again instead of making an new insert

Comment: It seems that ID is not being set - you repetedly try to insert element with same Id=0. Thats why you get the error. Take a look at @Id property, Could you try defining it as String ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  @Id
  @ObjectId
  public String id;
```

adding `@ObjectId` and type `String`.Seems the id is not able to generate as pointed by @marcinn

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#the-id-field)

> If the server receives a document that does not have the _id field
>   first, then the server will move the field to the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, but coming from a Relational database school of thought I was under the assumption that `_id` should always be a long and not a string...?http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/ also suggests the same?

Comment: @g0c00l.g33k so does my solution solves your problem

Comment: @singakash nope that doesn't seem to help too